# My brakes get mushy under heavy pressure

Tags: mountain-bike, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake

I have some Avid Juicy 5 on my Specialized SJ FSR '08 and the front brake gets mushy and looses brake power on long downhill trails.

Do I have to purge the brake lines to get performance back on track?

Comment: You could be overheating the brakes (which is easier with old brake fluid as it is hygroscopic and boils easier when more water is absorbed; new brake fluid would delay this, if it is the case).

Comment: Are you riding the brakes continuously?  Or are you using firmer on/off cycles ?   Has it always been like this or has it been getting worse?

Comment: @Batman Thanks! I will bleed my front brake and replace the old brake fluid. This situation was giving me lack of confidence on very technical terrain.

Comment: @Criggie I normally use firmer on/off cycles on flat terrain and avoid doing it over roots and rocks. When my bike was new, I never had this problems so I guess I just have to do as Batman suggests.
Thanks both for your comments!

Answer (score 2):

As @Batman has suggested brake fluid is hygroscopic. Over time moisture from the air is absorbed by the fluid. When the brakes get hot enough the  absorbed water will boil. This results in air bubbles forming in the fluid. While brake fluid is not compressible the air bubbles are. This results in a mushy or spongy feeling to the brakes. Once cooled the bubbles may be reabsorbed allowing the brakes to feel normal.
+

Comment: Also note that above is true for DOT brake fluids, mineral oil is hydrophobic. SRAM (Avid) use DOT only.

Comment: @Klaster_1 you are right. I already checked the manual and only DOT hygroscopic fluid can be used in Avid Juicy 3/5. I will bleed and replace the fluid to solve this.